# Is there any way to extract RTP extension header data using ffmpeg functions?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

I want to extract RTP extension header data while reading ffmpeg packets using `int av_read_frame(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt);`
But seems that ffmpeg skips RTP extension header data while creating `AVPacket` data ([link](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/7206b94fb893c63b187bcdfe26422b4e026a3ea0/libavformat/rtpdec.c#L643) to code ). ffmpeg makes `AVPackets` from `RTPPacket` data. So probably there is a way to get current `RTPPacket` after or before calling `av_read_frame`? ... or probably somebody knows another way?

Comment: it will be really weird if it's missing, are you sure? maybe try executing `ffmpeg -loglevel debug` on an rtp stream and look at the dump?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Did you find a solution? We tried accessing it via one of the IO Structs on the formatCtx, but currently there is no light in the tunnel

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this feature but only pushed it today for the fork of `ffmpeg-2.4.2` tag. Here is the [commit](https://github.com/Koshub/FFmpeg/commit/c7eeb33420ca6e5d3bd512f504cc90855c689438). 
For example in `iOS` you can do something like this:

```objc
AVPacket _packet; // Get your decoded packet
NSData *extData = nil;
if (_packet.extlen > 0) {
   extData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:_packet.ext length:_packet.extlen];
}
```